# YUI test error: window.getYUITestResults()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, yui, grover

I have error when I run the **YUI** tests via **PhantomJS** using **grover**:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'window.getYUITestResults()')

I found that this error occurs because I use **location.reload()** and PhantomJS have problem with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the solution:

```
if (window['phantom'] || window['_phantom']) return;
location.reload();
```

- **window['phantom']** - indicates presence **PhantomJS**, but when you use **grover** this property is absent :(
- **window['_phantom']** - indicates presence **PhantomJS** using **grover**

Using this simple solution you can skip as may code as you want, good luck!